# AS3: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert to flash.display.DisplayObject

Tags: actionscript-3

having some trouble with hitTestObject and now Flash is telling me it can't convert my ship to a display object.. my problem is the ship class extends Sprite to begin with so I don't know what's going on:

Compile error shows this:

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert Ship$ to flash.display.DisplayObject.
at Control/controlgame()
```

Control / controlgame() is this:

```
function controlgame(e:Event) {
        for (var i = 0; i < wprojectiles.length; i ++) {
            if (wprojectiles[i].x < -200 || wprojectiles[i].x > 750 || wprojectiles[i].y < -200 || wprojectiles[i].y > 600) {
                parent.removeChild(wprojectiles[i]);
                wprojectiles.splice(i,1);
            }
            if (wprojectiles[i].hitTestObject(Ship)) {
                parent.removeChild(wprojectiles[i]);
                wprojectiles.splice(i,1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Using the debugger, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert Ship$ to flash.display.DisplayObject.
at Control/controlgame()[C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\Flash Games\Games\Dodge\Control.as:29]
```

Line 29, seen in the above snippet, is this:

```
if (wprojectiles[i].hitTestObject(Ship)) {
```

Tearing my hair out here, tried everything I could think of and I get this error every single time, no matter what I do! Help would be so badly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

e: if it bears relevance, this is my document class file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you declare `Ship`? It looks like you're using a `Class` for your test instead of an instance... do you have something like `Ship = new ShipClass()` somewhere?

Comment: my ship class is called Ship. let me change things around and tell you how i go.

Comment: no dice, issue remained the same. i have my ship on the timeline/stage to begin with because if i try to put "var s = new Ship()" it says s is undefined. Also I just made an edit.. does this being the document class make any difference? I've not had this issue before with hit test object.. thanks.

Comment: Well, if you have a document class, you should declare something like `public var s:Ship = new Ship();` there. Then it shouldn't be undefined..

Comment: `public var s:Ship = new Ship();
  s.x = 200;
  s.y = 200;` throws an error for both lines, ie `C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\Flash Games\Games\Dodge\Control.as, Line 13 1120: Access of undefined property s.
`

Comment: Probably there's a misunderstanding here. Have a look at this [article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/creating_class_as3.html) that explains a class structure. The declaration of the ship should be declared like the "properties" in this example. Accessing the property would be *inside* the class methods or in the constructor... so setting `s.x = 200` should be inside a method!

Comment: I'm so lost lol.. i generally know my way around a class file (although you're right i was setting the x and y in the wrong spot) but i've never had this issue before and ive imported the same ship class from a previous project.. only in that project, the ship itself handled all collisions instead of a neutral class, ie, the document class. i'm getting more errors thrown after fixing what you've pointed out, but i don't know.. i need to take a break and look at it tomorrow.. thanks for your help though, i'm sure it will be key to fixing my main problem when i'm not too tired to concentrate. :)

Comment: @hazdog Alright. Good luck then :) If you wish, you can still post your code on pastie.org and I'll have a look at it.